# How do I show more payment options in the Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet with flutter?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I use the Stripe Flutter package. I currently tried some code and it shows the default checkout page with this code:

```
Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet
```

.. In here you can specify a credit card, google pay and apple pay. But in the web layout of stripe you can see there are more payment options visible like paypal and ideal (these option are enabled in my dashboard). Example page: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout

Is it possible to show more payment options in the stripe flutter package? Or do I need to use some sort of webview to load a web version?

Edit:
I want exactly this but then for fluttter: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/tree/master/Example/PaymentSheet%20Example